# When a line is not in the domain of a function.

Tags: calculus

Let us suppose that $f(x,y)$ is a function and a line such as $x=a$ (where $a$ is any real number) is not in the domain of that function. What would that imply about the graph around a point such as $(a,b),$ where $b$ is also any real number?

Comment: F(y), or F(x)? Generally, we say $x=5$ is not in the domain of $y=f(x)$ to mean that the *point* $x=5$ is not a value that can be "plugged into" the function.

Comment: I apologize, because I have not asked what I wanted to ask nor have I made myself clear. Let us suppose that f(x,y) is a function and a line such as x=a (where a is any real number) is not in the domain of that function. What would that imply about the graph around a point such as (a,b) (where b is also any real number)?

Comment: If you have a function of two variables with *real* values, then the "graph" is like a topography map in 3-dimensions (see, for instance, this [java grapher](http://www.calculator-grapher.com/graphers/function-grapher-2-var.html). Saying that $x=a$ is not in the domain means that there is no graph above that line (just like, when you have a function of one variable, if $x=k$ is not in the domain, then the graph has no point "above" the point $x=k$).

Comment: Please consider editing the body of the question and making yourself clear in it, instead of in the comments only.

Comment: If the line $x=a$ is not in the domain, then you cannot graph the function at $(a,b)$, just like you cannot graph $y=1/x$ at $0$. "near it", what it does depends on the function; it need not imply anything. The function $f(x,y) = xy/x$ is not defined on the line $x=0$, but the graph "near" points of the form $(0,b)$ is not in any way "weird". On the other hand, the graph of $f(x,y) = y/x$ is undefined on the line $x=0$, and it can "blow up" near points $(0,b)$ (to $\infty$ on one side and to $-\infty$ on the other, and do really weird things near $(0,0)$)

Comment: Thank you very much, but to probe the question a little deeper, what would happen to the limit around the point (a,b)? For example, suppose g(b)=0=f(a). What would happen to the limit as it proceeds to the point (a,b) on the graph f(x,y)=g(y)/f(x) and x=a is not in the domain of f(x,y)?

Comment: What happens to a one variable function near a point where it is undefined? Answer: It depends on the function. Exactly the same happens for two-variable functions. What happens near a point where it is undefined depends on the function; there are no general things to be said, deep or shallow.

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: See answer below: in and of itself, it tells us absolutely nothing other than what we already knew: it is undefined at points $(a,b')$ for any $b'$.

Answer (score 2):

It implies nothing; meaning, you cannot derive any useful information about what the function is doing "near" a point $(a,b)$ just from knowing that the function is undefined on the line $x=a$.

This is just like in $1$-variable: if I tell you that I have a function $y=f(x)$, and that it is undefined at $x=a$, what does that tell us about the behavior of the function near $x=a$ (that is, what does that tell us about $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$)? *Answer:* The information provided is insufficient to answer the question meaningfully; the fact that the function is undefined at $x=a$ does not, in and of itself, tell us anything about what the function does *near* $a$.

And the same is true for a function of two variables that is undefined on the line $x=a$. The only thing that it tells us about the behavior near $(a,b)$ is that it is undefined at the points $(a,b')$ for all $b'$ near $b$; in and of itself, however, it does not tell us *anything* about the behavior or values of the function at other points near $(a,b)$ (or far form $(a,b)$, for that matter).